# Overridden Hash Function in Java

Tags: java, hash, overriding, hashcode

[image]

My Question is if the hash functions calculate a distinct value for any object based on it's address that we can not know so on that note below on Image what is 16'0 and 16'1 refer to ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. 64 is the hexadecimal representation of 100. And 100 is the value the `hashCode` function returns in your example.

Comment: Thanks I got it it was just misunderstanding between toString() and hashCode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 100 in the code is always being returned as the hash code. The default toString using the hash-code of the object in Hexadecimal (i.e. base 16).  The note is drawing your attention to the fact that 100 in decimal is 64 in Hex.

Comment: That is okay I just had a conflict between toString() and hashCode().Thanks